# Inline variable in mysql query in php not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have following php code,

```
<?php
    $subject_set = mysqli_query($db_link, 'SELECT * FROM subjects');

    if(!$subject_set){
        die("Database subjects query failed: ".mysql_error());
    }

    while ($subject=mysqli_fetch_array($subject_set)) {
        echo "<li>{$subject["menu_name"]}</li>";
            $page_set = mysqli_query($db_link, 'SELECT * FROM pages WHERE subject_id= {$subject["id"]}');
            // $page_set = mysqli_query($db_link, 'SELECT * FROM pages WHERE subject_id='.$subject["id"]);

            if(!$page_set){
                die("Database pages query failed: ".mysql_error());
            }

            echo "<ul class=\"pages\">";

            while ($page=mysqli_fetch_array($page_set)) {
                echo "<li>{$page["menu_name"]}</li>";
            }

            echo "</ul>";

        }
    ?>
```

when I run this code it gives me an error when I getting 'page_set' values.In line `$page_set = mysqli_query($db_link, 'SELECT * FROM pages WHERE subject_id= {$subject["id"]}');` 
But I used commented line instead of the above line code works fine. Also `mysql_error()` doesn't show me the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$page_set = mysqli_query($db_link, 'SELECT * FROM pages WHERE subject_id= {$subject["id"]}');
```

to

```
$page_set = mysqli_query($db_link, "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE subject_id= {$subject["id"]}");
```

because PHP variables won't be processed unless they are in double-quoted strings.

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.php.net/language.types.string says

> **Note:** Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

Answer (score 1):

Because `$subject` not treated as `variable` it is used as string in your code. Use

```
 $page_set = mysqli_query($db_link, "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE subject_id={$subject['id']}");
```